# Web Scraping from Book title

Tags: python, web-scraping

I have book titles in a csv file and i am thinking if there is any way to scrape google books api in order to get author name for each book using python.

Comment: Hi, Please take a moment to look at [ask] and [mcve] to acquaint yourself with asking questions on SO and what is considered on topic.

Answer (score 0):

Google Books API is definitely an option. You could also have a look at https://isbndb.com/, although it appears to cost money. It's a book database that you could use as a source if you think it requires less set up than Google Books API. There are likely plenty of other free databases but I do not know if they are as comprehensive. I'll link some below.

- https://archive.org/ (API: https://blog.archive.org/developers/)
- https://www.amazon.com/Advanced-Search-Books/b/ref=sv_b_0?ie=UTF8&node=241582011
- https://openlibrary.org/developers/dumps